# How do I construct a regex string in Javascript using variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I've found similar questions and, thanks to those question, I think I've come close, but this still isn't doing what I want. (JQuery is already in use on this project, so I'm using it too.)

The snippet, as saved, works. If I comment out the current replace line and un-comment the one that's currently a comment, It seems to do nothing. It's supposed to find the first `maxWordschars` characters from the text, and any characters up to the next space and replace the string with what has been found.

```js
  $('.practice').each(function(){
      var maxWordschars = 34;
      var strippedString = $(this).text().trim();        
      var regexpattern = new RegExp("/^(.{" + maxWordschars + "}[^\s]*).*/");
      var newString = strippedString.replace(/^(.{34}[^\s]*).*/, "$1");
      //var newString = strippedString.replace(regexpattern, "$1");
      if (newString != strippedString){
        newString += "...";
      }      
      $(this).text(newString);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="practice">
  Let this be a long string of text that my script has to deal with to make it fit.
</div>
<br>
<div class="practice">
  Allow this considerably longer paragraph of text with multisylable enunciations to further quantify the effectiveness of my script
</div>
```

Comment: You have to double `\ ` characters in the string, because the string constant grammar *also* considers `\ ` to be a metacharacter.

Comment: That was a challenging comment to type.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts! I'll give it a try.

Comment: I tried `new RegExp("\/^...(\/");` and I tried `new RegExp("//^...(//");`. But I bet you're on to the solution.

Comment: You should *not* escape the delimiting `/` characters. In fact, in a *string* passed to `RegExp` you should not include those at all: `new RegExp("^(.{" + maxWordschars + "}[^\\s]*).*");`. You should also check `maxWordschars` that any special characters are escaped as well.

Comment: For reference, this is a **backslash**: \ and this is a **forward slash** (or just a **slash**): /

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var regexpattern = new RegExp("^(.{" + maxWordschars + "}\\S*).*");
```

```js
  $('.practice').each(function(){
      var maxWordschars = 34;
      var strippedString = $(this).text().trim();        
      var regexpattern = new RegExp("^(.{" + maxWordschars + "}\\S*).*");
      //var newString = strippedString.replace(/^(.{34}[^\s]*).*/, "$1");
      var newString = strippedString.replace(regexpattern, "$1");
      if (newString != strippedString){
        newString += "...";
      }      
      $(this).text(newString);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="practice">
  Let this be a long string of text that my script has to deal with to make it fit.
</div>
<br>
<div class="practice">
  Allow this considerably longer paragraph of text with multisylable enunciations to further quantify the effectiveness of my script
</div>
```

Comment: I found that `\\w*` works as well as `\\S*` and syntactically is what I really want to do. (Match word characters instead of matching non-space characters.)

Comment: `\w === [a-zA-Z0-9_]`  
`'my $a here'.replace(/^(.{3}\w*).*/, '$1...') // my ...`  
`'my $a here'.replace(/^(.{3}\S*).*/, '$1...') // my $a...`